# Highcharts X-Axis value on top of stacked column

Tags: highcharts

I'm using some PHP loops generate a series of charts for individuals.I'm trying to place the X-Axis category point on top of my column for each point. The relavent code is:

```
xAxis: {
        categories: [<?php echo implode(',', $year); ?>],
        title: {
            text: 'Year'        
        }
    },
    yAxis: [{
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'ADR'
        },
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>' + this.x.category + '</b>';
            },
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'black'
            }
        },
```

I'm unsure how to go about this i've tried `this.x`, `this.x.category`, `this.x.value` and so far I've not been able to get my x-axis category value. How do I do this in Highcharts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stack is a separate entity from the series or the point, so doesn't have direct access to the same properties.

But with a little digging, you can make the link from the stack to the x axis categories (I always just do a console.log(this) within the formatter to see what it can access...)

```
formatter: function() {
  var x = this.x;
  var cat = this.axis.chart.xAxis[0].categories[x];
  return cat;
}
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/xgucespk/

You could also just define your categories array outside of the chart, and reference that array for both the categories definition, and in the formatter function.

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/xgucespk/1/

Comment: Thank you very much that was great help to me